# How to delete the border in android when an input text field is selected?

Tags: android, html, css

When i select a input text field the android default browser draw a border around the input text field?

I tried this, but it does nothing.

```
input[type="text"]:focus { border: none; outline: none;}
```

Is it possible to have no border around the input text field when the text field is selected in the android browser?

Answer (score 4):

Try setting the background to transparent.

```
<EditText   
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
    android:hint="@string/input"  
    android:background="#00000000" 
/>
```